# Override [NotNull] Attribute correctly

Tags: c#, inheritance, resharper

I inherit from `ArrayList` and override the `Add` method (see below).
It's curious that the `Add()` method has marked the object value parameter as `[NotNull]` and the [documentation](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh421067.aspx) says "This value can be a null reference".

Anyway I've marked it now as `[CanBeNull]` (via a ReSharper annotation attribute).
But IntelliSense still gives me the cached documentation that marks the parameter as `[NotNull]`.

Why isn't the documentation overridden?

```
/// <summary>
/// Bla bla
/// </summary>
/// <param name="value">
/// This Attribute is marked as CanBeNull.
/// </param>
/// <returns></returns>
public override int Add([CanBeNull] object value)
{
    if (value != null)
    {
        // Do sth.
    }
}
```

Comment: It's not an attribute, it's a method parameter — use the proper terminology in order not to confuse anyone willing to answer. Also, consider using `List<T>` rather than `ArrayList`.

Answer (score 3):

Although overridden `[NotNull]` attributes with `[CanBeNull]` are respected by ReSharper's nullability analysis and are also shown in the Ctrl+Shift+F1 window, ReSharper incorrectly ignores them in the parameter info.

I created [RSRP-447900](https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/RSRP-447900).